# Display duplicate row values

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I am looking for a way to list all rows with a duplicate column value.

Example:
**Table Address**

```
House Person
23     Joe
23     Jane
27     Chris
29     Grandpa
```

Expected output:

```
House Person
23     Joe
23     Jane
```

I would like to do this so I can manipulate values of people who live in the same house.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. Now it just looks like you want us to do the work for you. I hope people will stop answering these questions where the OP clearly makes no effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by getting all house ids that have more than one person:

```
SELECT house
FROM myTable
GROUP BY house
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Then, you can join that with your original table to get the people who live in those houses:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable m
JOIN (SELECT house FROM myTable GROUP BY house HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) temp
   ON temp.house = m.house;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b13cd/1) example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select b.house, a.person from
    (
        select person,house
        from address
    )a,
    (
        select house,count(house) as cnt
        from address
        group by house
    )b
where a.house = b.house
and b.cnt > 1
```

Comment: Leave some comment why my answer down voted would be great.. :)